# Pass parameter to directive name in HTML as attribute

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, I do stuff like this all the time:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type"text" ng-model="model.name">
</div>
```

And I know that `ng-controller` and `ng-model` are Angular directives. I also know that I can make my own directives and use them like this (among others):

```
<div photo photo-caption="caption"></div>
<photo caption="caption" src="image.jpg"></div>
```

Now that's great. But is it possible to do something like this:

```
<photo="Tom's Cat" src="cat.jpg"></photo>
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `<div photo photo-caption="caption">` and `<photo caption="caption" src="image.jpg"></div>` is bad HTML. Does AngularJS make magic HTML tags and change the HTML spec?

Comment: @Sukima: Yes, it does :) That's why everyone loves it !

Comment: @Sukima, AngularJS really does make magic! Declaring it this way tells Angular's $compile to do stuff with the DOM. It's extremely expressive. Check this out: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Sigh, yet another nail in the coffin. Sticking with Ember.

Comment: @Titus: Did you take a look at my answer ? Is it what you are after ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem it's as close as I'll get. Thanks for the thorough answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't have a tag name have a value. Only attributes can have values.

---

I am not sure this is what you are after, but a few built-in directives support two forms: attribute (A) and element (E).

E.g. `ngSwitch` can take on of two forms:

1. Attribute: `<ANY ng-switch="expression" ...>`
2. Element: `<ng-switch on="expression" ...>`

Thus, the `expression` that needs to be evaluated is defined either on the `ngSwitch` attribute (if it is present) or on the `on` attribute (if `ngSwitch` is used as a custom tag).

In the directive's link function, this is implemented like this:

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    var watchExpr = attrs.ngSwitch || attrs.on;
    ...
```

So, it first looks for an attribute named `ngSwitch` (normalized name) and if it's not found (or is empty) it looks for an attribute named `on`.

---

You could implement a similar feature, if you want your `photo` directive to support different forms:

1. Attribute: `<div photo="My cool photo" src="..."></div>` or
2. Element: `<photo caption="My cool photo" src="..."></photo>`

e.g.:

```
.directive('photo', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        ...
        link: function photoPostLink(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.caption = attrs.photo || attrs.caption;
            ...
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 as well for the alternative form support.